# issues placing text over an image (CSS, relative positioning)

Tags: css, image, css-position

So my issue is thus; I have a image menu (block of 4 photos), I want over the top of each of these photos to display some text. I have done it before, but for some reason this time its all going pear shaped. I don't want to set the images as backgrounds within the css, as I consider them content and want them in the markup.

here is the css i have done:

```
#club_menu{
position:relative;
padding:1px;
width:99.5%;
height:400px;
/*border: 1px solid #A424A9;*/
}
#club_menu a{
position:relative;
width:295px;    
}
#club_menu a h2{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
#club_menu h2 span{
color:white;
font:bold 24px/45px Helvetica, sans-serif;
letter-spacing:-1px;
background-color:#A424A9;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
opacity:0.7;
padding:10px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="club_menu">
            <a href="#">
            <h2><span>Aquum Tuesday</span></h2>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/menu_aquum.jpg" width="295" height="195" /> 
            </a>
            <a href="#">
            <h2><span>Movida Wednesday</span></h2>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/menu_movida.jpg" width="295" height="195" />
            </a>
            <a href="#">
            <h2><span>Whisky Thursday</span></h2>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/menu_whisky.jpg" width="295" height="195" />
            </a>
            <a href="#">
            <h2><span>Jalouse Tuesday</span></h2>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/menu_jalouse.jpg" width="295" height="195" />
            </a>
            </div>
```

I have been playing around for over an hour now and the labels are simply all over the place. My images are in place perfectly. Can somebody with some skill with CSS, please enlighten me.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the css, it looks like the images arn't positioned absolutly inside the link object add a #club_menu img {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}

try specifiying the size AND width of the link element as a block using (display:block; or display:inline-block if you need the blocks to be inline with each other), with position relative

Then any child elements (h2, image) postions can specified absolutly will be relative to the link.

You'll mostly likely need to incorporate the previous answer about z-index to get the text OVER the image.

Comment: You should probably also make the a objects block elements with a display:block;

Comment: thats done it for the labels, now all my images are on the left.

Comment: on the left of what? are the labels now positioned correctly related to the link, or to the images? try specifiying the size AND width of the a element as a block, with position relative, then any childrens (h2, image) postions specified absolutly will be relative to the link.

Comment: ok so, labels are correctly position on top of the correct images. However before the images formed a square of 4. They are all now positioned on the left, one after another down the page completely out of the club_menu div.

Comment: Ahh ok, thats the links, not the images, because we made them block elements, try changing it from display:block; to display:inline-block;

Comment: display:block makes the element a block (which doesn't allow html next to it) inline block does the same, which allows your links to have width and height but still be part of a flow layout http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: whack it in your answer and ill select it mate. Thankyou for that.

Comment: Added in the relevant bits that answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add z-index - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I tried using the z-index, basically the result of that is two labels are in the right place but on the wrong images, and the other two are completely out of place.